# Microsoft Visual Studio C# Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've managed to get Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition working on my machine,

I had a specific question about settings configuration for C# prioritization.

Tools > Import and Export Settings > Have all been reset to the best configuration for C#.

Whenever I open a new application development project (like console or WPF) there is no "BUILD" option in the toolbar on the top right (which contains 'File', 'Edit', 'View', 'Debug', etc. options).

This is a highly useful shortcut. What would be the best path for setup in order to attain that configuration?

Very Respectfully.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring both the menu bar and tool bar can be done via Tools->Customize.

Comment: Thank you. I traced the menu paths and restarted the environment. The options are available for direct tools now.